# Как я могу изменить цену значения нижней оси графика? | GraphView

Tags: java, android, android-studio, graph

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
Как я могу изменить цену значения нижней оси графика?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете сами указать цену оси x, первым параметром `x`  `new DataPoint(x, y)`

Можно так же задать максимум и минимум:

```
graph.getViewport().setMinX(x_min);
graph.getViewport().setMaxX(x_max);
graph.getViewport().setXAxisBoundsManual(true);
```

По всей видимости вам хочется использовать дату по оси x, вот ссылка на документацию с данным кейсом
https://github.com/jjoe64/GraphView/wiki/Dates-as-labels